# Cell selection jumps after pressing {enter} in Excel

Tags: excel, cell

I have a code which cleans up the data I just entered.  After I run this code, it sets my cell on Column B which gets me set for the next entry.  After I enter data into the cell, and only after I press the enter key, the cell will jump to column G of the next row.  If I tab or move via arrow key before the enter, I go to Column B of the next row (as it should work.)

Has anyone experienced this before? Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

When using tab in Excel, then Enter, it acts differently than using the arrow key, then Enter.  After consecutive tabs are complete, when you press Enter, it should go to the next row to the column just before your first tab.

Imagine you have a sheet with First Name, Last Name, Company, Zip Code in columns A, B, C, and D respectively.  You begin in cell A1 entering first name > TAB > last name > TAB > company > TAB > zip.  At this point, you've just entered the zip into cell D1.  If you were to press enter, you would go to cell A2 which would prepare you to enter the next record.

Comment: Michael,  That's so simple.  I never considered that. However, I tested that theory, ending my data entry on column U this time, ran my macro, and still end up on G upon pressing enter.  Thanks for weighing in, but I'm still on the hunt for my answer.

Comment: Perhaps the macro is affecting something.  I'm not that experienced with macros in Excel but I'm sure someone else may be able to help.  I suggest you share the macro code here so it can be analyzed.